# Good Multivariable Calculus MOOC?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My second semester of Software Engineering just started in my university. I have the subject named as 'Calculus of Multi-variables'. In first semester, we studied Calculus One and Calculus Two and I used the Courses of Prof. Jim Fowler on Coursera (namely [Calculus One](https://www.coursera.org/learn/calculus1) and [Calculus Two: Sequence and Series](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-calculus)) as a source to cover the topics more clearly and quickly.

But now I searched on Coursera for Calculus Three or Multivariable Calculus and I did not find any course, there was one though but that was in Turkish Language, not English. From google I came to know about the M2O2C2 ([Massively Multivariable Open Online Calculus Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/m2o2c2)) on Coursera of same Prof. Jim Fowler, but whenever I open the link it does not redirect me to any course, instead it redirects to Coursera's Homepage.

I got to know about MIT's [Multivariable Calculus](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/#) but it's topics are not really of the Multivariable Calculus, this course has the High School Topics of Physics, it does not have lectures on 3D-Plane, 3D-Space and how we use multivariable functions etc.

I looked at some other courses as well, but same, the topics are not the same as of my University's Course. Below is the picture of topics of my University's Course. Kindly look at the picture and provide any **free online source** that has lectures on these topics. Thanks in advanced.

[image]
[image]

Comment: mit's course will certainly cover this

Comment: The 3D-Plane and 3D-Space would be covered in MIT's course?

Comment: and the multivariable functions, their limits, their derivatives, their integrals etc. all of this?

Comment: yes, all of those topics are completely standard

Comment: MIT's curriculum is basiccaly what you expect from a multivariable calculus course.

Comment: Ted Shifrin also has multi-variable calculus videos up for a year long sequence! Just google his name in youtube.